# d3.js Partition layout - combine parents that don't have leaf children

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js Partition layout - is there a way to combine parent Nodes that don't have children?
[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faDFs.png) and I would like to make it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYK9r.png)

I have parents like: `/`, `app`, and `surface`. `surface` has children nodes such as `accelerated_surface_mac.cc` and other files under it. Other parents (`/`, `app`) don't have leaf childrens (`<file.cc>`), so I would like to combine them to save screen real estate.

I'm using https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#partition
An example I referred to while putting my partition together is this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2e73ec84221cb9773f4c